# Matching digits in Notepad++ extended search mode

Tags: notepad++, text-editors

Notepad++'s manual is rather vague on the special character for numerical used in extended search mode.
It says: \d### - Decimal value (between 000 and 255)
but literally entering "\d###" doesn't match anything.

What I am trying to do is to replace

```
if VarA == 12
  VarB = 1
```

with

```
if VarA == 12
  Var12=1
  VarB=1
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having *exactly* the same problem! I found a workaround. First, use the 'Extended' search mode (what you call the 'interim mode') to find and replace all the newline characters with some random character that's not in the text. For example, I replaced all my newline characters with a tilde ('~'). Then, switch to 'Regular expression' search mode, and now you can search for newlines by referring to them by your replaced character. Once you're done manipulating the text with find and replace, switch the random character back to newlines. That's it!

Answer (score 2):

I was just looking for an answer to this question. After taking a look on the NP++ wiki, I don't think `\d` is matching what we want it to match.

> \d
>   the decimal representation of a byte, made of 3 digits in the 0-9 range

It's not matching a regular numeric character, it's matching a byte code. Follow the `\d` with a 3-digit number and it will match the corresponding ASCII character.

In other words, `\d032` matches the space character, `\d033` matches an exclamation mark and so on. [See here for a list of codes](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Unfortunately, this means you can't just match "any digit" using the extended options, you'll have to use the regular expressions and find a way around the new line issue.

Comment: You should be able to use \r\n for the new line or \n (dependent on your OS.)

Comment: @Blackbeagle: No you can't, that's exactly the reason for this question. NP++ doesn't match new lines in the regular expression mode, but it has an interim mode that matches special characters like `\n`, but you can't use eg `[0-9]` on that.

Answer (score 1):

```
if VarA == 12  
    VarB = 1

if VarA == 16  
    VarB = 0
```

Using Find/Replace with Regular expression

Find what: `if VarA == ([0-9]+)`
Replace with: `if VarA == \1 \n\t Var\1=1`

Run "Replace All"

Result:

```
if VarA == 12  
     Var12=1  
    VarB = 1

if VarA == 16  
     Var16=1  
    VarB = 0
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: While this works now, bear in mind that the original question was asked before Notepad++ improved its regular expression engine.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to clarify:  As I understand your code what you are trying to do is to search for:

if VarA ==

and then store the numeric value and then replace it with

if VarA ==   Var=1.

The problem isn't the searching, it is that you are trying to store the value.  I don't know if the search/replace function can do such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Using the character classses in regular expression search mode in notepad++ you can search for a character that exists in a certain range using the following syntax
[a-z] so in the previous example you search for any character from a to z.
So using the same method you can search for one decimal digit ranging from 0 to 9 by writing [0-9] in the search bar.
So for example if you need to search for number that contains more than one decimal digit (for example 3 decimal digits) you can do that by writing the following in the search bar
[0-9][0-9][0-9]

Here are the link to the notepad++ user manual which is the reference of this answer
https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/#regular-expressions

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).